# Dying hair only slightly

Tags: hair

My hair is already dark brown but I want it just a little more brownish. I think dying it is a no no since its really obvious its fake. I attach some pics of what I am looking for. It should only be noticeable when the sun is hitting it. Maybe some kind of bleach?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a question for a hairdresser! If I were you, the next time I get my hair cut, I'd show these pictures to the hairdresser and ask their advice. Tell them you want to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use slow gradual lightener at home. It works very slowly, so you’ll know when to stop without looking obviously dyed.

On brown hair they give reddish tones, so it may be what you are looking for.

Just two examples:

https://www.pharmacyonline.com.au/john-frieda-sheer-blonde-go-blonder-lightening-spray-103ml?gclid=Cj0KCQjw4fHkBRDcARIsACV58_GeGeFlLW485-oGVOMadMO5Oq_QshRchZPr63Iseq-BrMugf8EV_MMaAnuCEALw_wcB

https://www.cosmeticcapital.com.au/loreal-paris-casting-sunkiss-jelly-02-dark-blonde?gclid=Cj0KCQjw4fHkBRDcARIsACV58_F86SzgTXVqK1rb2vUww8PK_j69eAUJ5X3TuvDJ5u8G1EMJW6FSOiMaAnGpEALw_wcB